# How to optimize this function calculating the categorical crossentropy of two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I want to calculate the categorical crossentropy of two numpy arrays. Both arrays have the same length.

1. `y_true` contains around 10000 2D arrays, which are the labels
2. `y_pred` contains 10000 2D arrays, which are my predictions

The result should be a 1D numpy array which contains all the categorical crossentropy values for the arrays. The formular is:

[image]

Here x_true is the i-th element of one true vector and x_pred is the i-th element of the prediction vector.

My implementation looks like this, but it is very slow. The reshaping is done to convert the 2D arrays to 1D arrays to simple iterate over them.

```
def categorical_cross_entropy(y_true, y_pred):
    losses = np.zeros(len(y_true))
    for i in range(len(y_true)):
        single_sequence = y_true[i].reshape(y_true.shape[1]*y_true.shape[2])
        single_pred = y_pred[i].reshape(y_pred.shape[1]*y_pred.shape[2])
        sum = 0
        for j in range(len(single_sequence)):
            log = math.log(single_pred[j])
            sum = sum + single_sequence[j] * log
        sum = sum * (-1)
        losses[i] = sum
    return losses
```

A conversion to tensors is not possible, since `tf.constant(y_pred)` fails in a `MemoryError`, because every 2D array in `y_true` and `y_pred` has roughly the dimensions 190 x 190. So any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.special.xlogy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.xlogy.html).  For example,

```
In [10]: import numpy as np

In [11]: from scipy.special import xlogy
```

Create some data:

```
In [12]: y_true = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(8, 200, 200))

In [13]: y_pred = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(8, 200, 200))
```

Compute the result using `xlogy`:

```
In [14]: -xlogy(y_true, y_pred).sum(axis=(1, 2))
Out[14]: 
array([-283574.67634307, -283388.18672431, -284720.65206688,
       -285517.06983709, -286383.26148469, -282200.33634505,
       -285781.78641736, -285862.91148953])
```

Verify the result by computing it with your function:

```
In [15]: categorical_cross_entropy(y_true, y_pred)
Out[15]: 
array([-283574.67634309, -283388.18672432, -284720.65206689,
       -285517.0698371 , -286383.2614847 , -282200.33634506,
       -285781.78641737, -285862.91148954])
```

If you don't want the dependence on `scipy`, you can do the same thing with `np.log`, but you might get a warning if any value in `y_pred` is 0:

```
In [20]: -(y_true*np.log(y_pred)).sum(axis=(1, 2))
Out[20]: 
array([-283574.67634307, -283388.18672431, -284720.65206688,
       -285517.06983709, -286383.26148469, -282200.33634505,
       -285781.78641736, -285862.91148953])
```